# JavaScript : Piece of code that breaks my modals

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have a piece of code that will create a contextual menu on right-click on one input in my page. The code is supposed to add "{Keyword: }" to the input. The problem is when I add the JS below all the modals that I use stop working (not displaying). The modals are activated by a button click.

Contexctual menu HTML:

```
<div id='cntnr'>
   <ul id='items'>
      <li>{Keyword:fallback}</li> 
      <li>{KeyWord:fallback}</li> 
   </ul>
</div>
```

Contexctual menu JS:

```
 $("#headline11").on("contextmenu",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#cntnr").css({"left": e.pageX-3, "top": e.pageY-3});
   $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200, startFocusOut);

 });

 function startFocusOut(){
   $(document).on("click",function(){
   $("#cntnr").hide();        
   $(document).off("click");
   });
 }

 $("#items > li").click(function(){
 $("#headline11").val($(this).text().replace("fallback", " "));
 var input1 = document.getElementById("headline11");
 setInputSelection(input1, 9, 10);
 });
```

Button:

```
<button onclick="load();setTimeout(myFunction, 10)" class="myBtn1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#build">1 - Create campaign</button>
```

The modal:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Modal Preview-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="build" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Your Campaign Preview1</h4>
        </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="hoursSaved"></div>
                Some text here.
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use {Keyword: Whatever here} in my input and submit, the modals stop working, but when I remove the JS above everything works, except the contextual menu of course.

It took me hours to debug my code and find what part of it is causing the problem, but I'm unable to understand why. Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,

EDIT: Here is a JsFiddle as requested in the comments. You'll have to run the code between each test to see the difference.
https://jsfiddle.net/yagami889/xpvt214o/470697/
You'll have to use the contextual menu to add the {Keyword:} you can enter whatever you want after ":", it won't work if you past it.

Comment: Can you please submit snippet or jsfiddle, with every functions include which you used it

Comment: Any errors? also as Jagjeet said, jsfiddle would be good. Here is one working with the code you supplied but missing modal button onclick function https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/vL3uxans/

Comment: No error. I've edited my post with the JsFiddle. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work for you guys?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the $(document).off("click") inside the startFocusOut() function. If you remove this line, it works. Why do you need that line?

Comment: I don't know, I have reused an existing code. I would say that I've found the solution at the same time, but differently. In fact, in the same function, instead of using document I use "#cntnr" and it works the same but I don't know why. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had to use:

```
function startFocusOut(){
   $("#cntnr").on("click",function(){
   $("#cntnr").hide();        
   $("#cntnr").off("click");
   });
 }
```

Instead of:

```
function startFocusOut(){
   $(document).on("click",function(){
   $("#cntnr").hide();        
   $(document).off("click");
   });
 }
```